# Amazon Redshift Stuck at 99% during resize operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I've been waiting several hours for my redshift cluster complete a resize. It has been stuck at 99% complete with 0 time and 0 data remaining for 2 hours now. A quick web and forum search shows that this is fairly common. All the threads have no details about resolution, other than that an AWS rep PMs the user.

This is a cross-post from the AWS discussion forums.

Comment: hi, how much data are you resizing? I am considering redshift as my new data warehouse and would like to know a rough estimate on how long the resizing will take. also please let me know whether you are migrating SSD to SSD, SDD to HDD, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I contacted AWS support in person (at the SF Market street loft).

It turns out that copying the last 1% of the data in a resize can take 80 to 90% of the time. In this case, the first 99% of the data was copied in 1 hour. The rest of the resize took 10 more hours. Unfortunately, neither the documentation nor the progress bar and time remaining indicators reflect this.

Your milage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry about your experience with the resize.

We are aware of the issue with display showing 99% for long time and we are working on providing our customers with better messaging about the resize progress.

Also I would love to see why did it take 2 hours to complete your resize process. Do you mind contacting me at marceta@amazon.com with more data so we can troubleshoot the issue?